# Remove Azure Long Term Backup from vault in Powershell, now cannot re-set

Tags: powershell, azure

I have two different databases in my Azure sql server, and had Long term backup configured on both.

I wanted to remove the backup from the recovery services vault for just one, but even though I coded to check for that one name (with "xxx" in the name), it also removed the backup for the other database ("yyy").

Now, in the portal for that other database ("yyy"), when I go to the database/restore/long-term/AzureVaultBackups blade it shows "TemplateBladeVirtualPart" "SQLAZUREEXTENTION".

And if I try to re-set the backup (in the portal) for "yyy" in the Sql Server/Long Term Backup Retention blade, it never assigns the policy (it also does not show an error). I can, however, re-assign the backup for "xxx".   Here is the code that removed the backup:

```
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $recoveryServiceVaultName
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault

$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -FriendlyName $vault.Name

ForEach ($container in $containers)
{
   $items = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase

   ForEach ($item in $items)
   {
      if ($item.name -like "*xxx*") {
      write-host "Item is systemstore"
      $item
      # Remove the backups from the vault
      ###################################
       Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -item $item   -ea SilentlyContinue 
      }
   }

   Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
}
```

I have also tried to re-assign the long term backup to the "yyy" database via code, but it fails on the "`set-AzureRMSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy`" command with the error "BadRequest: the server and the recoveryServicesVault should be under the same subscription and resource group"  (and they already are).
My questions are:

1. what is wrong with my code that it also removed the backup from yyy? and
2. how do I fix yyy so that I can apply long term backup?
3. why am I getting the BadRequest error on the "`set-AzureRMSqlDatabaseBackupLongTermRetentionPolicy`"  when my server and vault are in the same subscription and resource group?

Comment: well, obviously, both your items got passed to the script block that did the remove from backup, so check that, but what really bugs me, you unregister every backup container, what happens when you don't disable the backup protection on one of items, but disable backup container?

Comment: I was following the example "Delete long-term retention backups using PowerShell"  at the end of 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-long-term-backup-retention-powershell

Comment: I realized I was missing "-RemoveRecoveryPoints" on the Disable-AzureRMRecoveryServicesBackupProtecion line.  I added this and re-ran.  Now the  database/restore/long-term/AzureVaultBackups blade no longer shows "TemplateBladeVirtualPart" "SQLAZUREEXTENTION"  but I still cannot assign a ltr policy to that db in the sqlserver/Long Term Retention Backup blade.  If I try via Powershell, I get the same error as mentioned in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been using to remove long term backups:

```
# We need to set recovery services context to work with recovery vault
$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name '{VaultName}'
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
# Get protection containers to work with those
$containers = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureSQL -Status Registered
foreach ($container in $containers) {
    $item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $container -WorkloadType AzureSQLDatabase
    # possibly need another iterator here
    Disable-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $item -RemoveRecoveryPoints
    Unregister-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -Container $container
}
```